Cypress conditional passing the test without running the rest of the code
So here is the scenario for the Cypress test I need to create:

Visit the website, check if project exist
2a). If it does - change the name and pass the test without running
the rest of the     code outside of then().
2b). If it doesn’t - run the rest of the code outside the code that
will create the     project


Here is the code:
   it("1. Apollo - Create tented project with estimate and team", () => {
cy.visit(website)
projectPageObject.searchProject(projectName);
cy.get(".project_name")
  .then(project => {
    if(project.length>0){
      project[0].click();
      cy.wait(5000);
      projectPageObject.clickOnEditProject();
      projectPageObject.elements.projectNameInput()
                                .clear()
                                .type(projectName + id);                
      projectPageObject.updateProject(); 

    } else {
      cy.log("Project doesn't exist yet!")
    }
  })
  projectPageObject.createTheBrandNewProject();

The method createTheBrandNewProject() contains multiple then() chains. This prevents me from placing that code inside the else block, as Cypress does not allow using then() inside another then(). Additionally, using a boolean flag variable inside the then() block doesn't work due to its asynchronous nature.
I considered writing the boolean value to a file since I found a method that can read the file without using a then() block, but it didn't work in my case (I'm unsure why).
Is there any way to actually overcome this?

Can you please clarify this - what is the project that may or may not exist, i.e. what is page being tested?

Also, why are you even having to check? Why are you not setting the test up correctly so that it consistently runs the test?

So this particular app is used to create projects on which multiple different systems operate. We use a bunch of envs in our company and pretty often base of project is wiped out completely. So when we run tests, the first step is to create a project, then use it in different systems. The thing is that creating this project each time we run the test is time consuming so the it would be more efficient is to not create a test project if it already exist. It is not incorrect set up of tests, this is the flow that fits our model of systems.

You should know that the else part would never executes, since the condition project.length == 0 would mean that the prior cy.get(".project_name") has failed and so causes the whole test to fail.

Feel free to change anything in the code to make it work.

There's not enough detail to know exactly what to change, can only give you a general method. Be aware you are going against recommended practice.

I'm happy to provide any details needed to get some actual help, but not sure what more informations you would like to see. Could you specify?

If you know for sure that that the search has completed and the search results are displayed, you can use a Cypress.$() check to perform your if/else logic.
It would be something like
const projectExists = Cypress.$(".project_name").length > 0;
if (projectExists) then {

} else {
  projectPageObject.createTheBrandNewProject()
}

But you must account for loading yourself, you can't rely on cy.get('.project_name') to retry, since that will fail if the project doesn't appear in the search results.
So if there is a title or other page text that always shows up above the search results, check for that first.
Alternatively, use a polling method shown here How to check for an element that may not exist using Cypress
